# How to select an alternative style set for an xft font?

Tags: terminal, emacs, fonts

I like the [Fantasque Sans Mono](https://github.com/belluzj/fantasque-sans) font, and they have a style set (ss01) which has a more "traditional" design for the letter *k*, but I don't know how to select it in Emacs or in urxvt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should already know the basics:

- install the font and
- use `fc-list` to see that it shows the font, and
- use the family name shown in the output of `fc-list` in your X resources.

The question is about stylistic sets, i.e., [a feature of the fonts](https://github.com/belluzj/fantasque-sans/blob/master/Sources/FantasqueSansMono-Regular.sfd#L46):

```
OS2Vendor: 'PfEd'
Lookup: 1 0 0 "'ss01' Stylistic Set 1 - No loop k" { "'ss01' Stylistic Set 1 - No loop k-1" ("noloop") } ['ss01' ('DFLT' <'dflt' > 'cyrl' <'dflt' > 'grek' <'dflt' > 'latn' <'dflt' > ) ]
Lookup: 1 0 0 "'ss02' Stylistic Set 2 - Flat base i" { } ['ss02' ('DFLT' <'dflt' > 'cyrl' <'dflt' > 'grek' <'dflt' > 'latn' <'dflt' > ) ]
Lookup: 1 0 0 "'ss03' Stylistic Set 3 - No base serif i" { } ['ss03' ('DFLT' <'dflt' > 'cyrl' <'dflt' > 'grek' <'dflt' > 'latn' <'dflt' > ) ]
MarkAttachClasses: 1
```

The stylistic-set feature is discussed in *[Using OpenType Features on the Web](http://blog.webtype.com/?p=4085)*, e.g., making variations of fonts using the stylistic sets.  Without some work, you won't get these variations since fontconfig has no capability for selecting stylistic-sets.  You would have to **modify** the scripts in this font to use that as the default, and (using the modified scripts) **generate** ".ttf" files using that stylistic-set.

Further reading:

- [Stylistic Set 1 - No loop k, build as default? #67](https://github.com/belluzj/fantasque-sans/issues/67)
  bug report discusses this problem without providing a solution.
- [Stylistic Sets](https://glyphsapp.com/tutorials/stylistic-sets) (for *Glyphs* application)

Comment: So the short answer is that it cannot be done? (except by compiling new TTF files, of course)

Comment: yes, that's what I meant by **generate**